# android videoView java.io.filenotfoundexception no content provider

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I have a problem on a android phone. I'm trying to create some app that will play some stream. Stream is rtsp... But i have a problem. I'm using a videoView to play a stream and it looks good. I tested it on a motorola that has a android 2.3.7 and on sony ericsoon xperia mini pro with a 2.3.4 android. 
Problem is when i try to test it on a HTC One X with a ICS 4.04 system.

```
video.setVideoPath(url);
video.setOnPreparedListener(this);

@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        media_width = mp.getVideoWidth();
        media_height = mp.getVideoHeight();

        if (media_width > 0 && media_height > 0) {
            resize();
            video.start();
        } else {
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        }       
        loading.cancel();
        //video.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        startThreads();
    }
```

When i try to put some string in uri  in LogCat i catch this:
09-20 16:33:27.660: E/MediaPlayer(18521): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/xxx/programer_aac
Where is a problem???? This works fine in other android phones....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't found a answer, but i can say that it is a htc problem. I tested it on S3 and it worked like a charm, so the problem must bee with a htc.

Comment: I´m having this with ´Samsung´ and Emulators